# XMLHttpRequest object status code of 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a Javascript function using an XMLHttpRequest object, but the status I keep getting returned is 0. I've done lots of searching, and all I've come up with is that 0 is an undefined error and can be caused by a myriad of reasons. As such, I'm hoping you guys can spot the error in my code.

```
function initiateIPP(ID, Token)
    {
        var POSTRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        POSTRequest.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (POSTRequest.readyState == 4)
            {
                if (POSTRequest.status == 200)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    alert("An error has occured, response code = " + POSTRequest.status);
                }
            }
        }
        var parameters = "SessionId=" + ID + "&SST=" + Token;
        POSTRequest.open("POST", "https://demo.ippayments.com.au/access/index.aspx", true)
        POSTRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        POSTRequest.send(parameters)
        window.open("IPPPage.html");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I added a withCredentials line to my code but that doesn't seem to have made a difference.
    var parameters = "SessionId=" + ID + "&SST=" + Token;
            POSTRequest.withCredentials = true;
            POSTRequest.open("POST", "https://demo.ippayments.com.au/access/index.aspx", true)
            POSTRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            POSTRequest.send(parameters)
            window.open("IPPPage.html");

Comment: Does this helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752657/xmlhttprequest-status-always-returning-0

Comment: I did come across the issue of different origins... it could be the problem, I'm not sure, but if it is I'm not sure if it's really feasible to do something about it. Maybe I have to ask IPP how they expect me to send data to them...

Comment: If you are facing Cross Origin Resource issue, you probably should run using some server, could be apache, or another way would be to set `--disable-web-security` flag to your chrome browser...

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar `--disable-web-security` will only solve the issue for him.

Comment: Exactly, @gabeio is correct; this needs to work WITHOUT forcing people to go fiddling with settings in their browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrated properly with the IPPayments page at https://demo.ippayments.com.au/access/index.aspx, you need to use the Direct Post method. Instead of using the XMLHttpRequest object, use a HTML form to submit the ID and token. For example -

```
<form action="https://demo.ippayments.com.au/access/index.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="SST" value="1243123123123123123"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="SessionID" value="53535434535345"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was doing everything in the code-behind (this is an ASP.NET application/website) and just encoding the SessionID and SST as GET parameters and redirecting to the page that way.

Answer (score 2):

"https://demo.ippayments.com.au/access/index.aspx" this should be same domain with your javascript, otherwise, you should set :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

on target page's response header to get work. See http://enable-cors.org/

For example you can put below in web.config on **target server**:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Wait a sec, you're saying I need to set something in the other page's response header? How? o_O

Comment: @MichaelSmith for that you should search about settings response headers from your server

Comment: @MichaelSmith I see you use aspx, so I guess you can set in web.config.

Comment: Adding that to web.config hasn't helped. :(

Comment: mm.... can you control the target server? you should add in target aspx's server, not the server you send the request.

Comment: What do you mean by target server? There's two servers involved here: the server with the Javascript on the page, and the IP Payments server that I'm trying to send values to.

Comment: @MichaelSmith the server you are requesting that ajax call with. (no javascript server)

Comment: Is " the IP Payments server that I'm trying to send values to."

Comment: Ah, I follow. No I can't go messing with stuff on their server. I can email them and ask if their server is setup to allow cross-domain requests, but I won't get a reply until Monday or later. I was hoping I could fix the problem myself before then, hence this question.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Can you check that this is the issue by sending a test request to see their headers and double check that they do not already have this header... (if they do already have the answer is going to be different...)

Comment: I'm not sure how to send a test sorry, can you explain and/or give me some example code? Web programming is really not my strong point. :(

Comment: Just press f12 on your browser to open your developer tool, switch to Network, select your request and see the response header.

Comment: https://www.hurl.it/ use this with just the url (don't put the authentication) and just hit send the headers are shown to you and if it says `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` then you have a different issue. or what Andy said...

Comment: The console said this: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://demo.ippayments.com.au/access/index.aspx. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

I don't know if the problem is on my end or their end, will look at the headers.

EDIT: Looking at the header, I'm not seeing anything about access control. Is that the problem then?

Comment: Yeah then the issue is you need to tell them to allow what AndyChen is saying.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this late, but I wanted to ask; is there another way to send POST/GET data to a server? I tried using an XMLHttpRequest object because that was the first thing I came across, but presumably that's not how it's normally done with IP Payments, otherwise this problem wouldn't exist.

Comment: You can use JSONP or Proxy to do the same things.
For payment I'll suggest you to create a proxy to do server to server request.

Comment: That seems complicated, but I'll look into it I guess, thanks.